# Bootstrap multilevel collapsing navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[example multilevel menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUOIS.png)

Hello, who could help me to do the same menu in bootstrap.
The first menu opens on hover and next dropdowns opens on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-menus in dropdowns aren't a good idea due to the mobile web, but here is an example with Bootstrap 3

http://www.bootply.com/86684#

Comment: this is not the same as in my image, I'm wondering how to expand menus in the same menu.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know that's what you want just from that image?

Comment: and what is unclear, simple menu that is opening on hover and next submenu is opening on click down....